# Write some text and save on my android phone

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to save some text on file (test.txt) on my android phone but unsuccessful. This is my code example:

```
procedure TDM.WriteLog(text:string);
var
   myFile : TextFile;


 begin


   // Try to open the Test.txt file for writing to
   AssignFile(myFile, System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.tpath.getdocumentspath,'test.txt'));
   ReWrite(myFile);

   // Write a couple of well known words to this file
   WriteLn(myFile, text + sLineBreak );


   // Close the file
   CloseFile(myFile);


 end;
```

When i locate file on my phone i open file but it is empty. What I missed?

Comment: In this case I would use something from [TFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile_Methods) class.

Comment: @TomBrunberg WriteLog('some text'). It is string that i want to write.

Comment: It's time to stop using legacy IO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to create a text file in Android (it's the same with iOS and macOS of course) you can use the [`WriteAllText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.WriteAllText) class procedure that belongs to the TFile class. You have to add in the uses clause `System.IOUtils`.

```
TFile.WriteAllText(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'test.txt'), 'content');
```

When you want to store a text file, or in general data related to your app, it's recommended that you use the GetDocumentsPath. This is a modern way to create a text file but it's not the only one; consider also that you could:

1. Use a TStringlist and then call `SaveToFile('path')`
2. If you are using a memo it has the `SaveToFile('path')` function
3. Use the [`TStreamWriter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter) class (and the StreamReader to read the content)